# operating on sub group inside data frame very slow

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a data frame containing data about number of pushups done by different people(represented by id column) on four days of a week. I have to do the following

- Find a running sum(cumulative cost) of the pushups for each id
- At each day, I want to add a column which shows the number of pushups done on the next day. (NOTE that : Since on the last day, we do not know how many pushups were done the next day, we consider only till rows n-1))

I have written this by first 'arrange'ing the column by (id,dayofweek) and then created a temporary data frame on which I performed all these operations iteratively. The problem with this is that on a huge data frame, it's very very slow. Is there a more elegant way to do both of these things. Please my code and the input and output data frame below

Input(after arranging)

```
> df
   id dayofweek pushupcount cumulativepushups nextdaypushupcount
1   1      day1         100                 0                  0
2   1      day2         240                 0                  0
3   1      day3         200                 0                  0
4   1      day4         170                 0                  0
5   2      day1         220                 0                  0
6   2      day2         190                 0                  0
7   2      day3         300                 0                  0
8   2      day4         150                 0                  0
9   3      day1         260                 0                  0
10  3      day2         160                 0                  0
11  3      day3         200                 0                  0
12  3      day4         210                 0                  0
```

Output

```
> df
   id dayofweek pushupcount cumulativepushups nextdaypushupcount
1   1      day1         100               100                240
2   1      day2         240               340                200
3   1      day3         200               540                170
5   2      day1         220               220                190
6   2      day2         190               410                300
7   2      day3         300               710                150
9   3      day1         260               260                160
10  3      day2         160               420                200
11  3      day3         200               620                210
```

Creating data

```
#creating data
id = c(1,2,3,2,1,2,3,1,3,2,1,3)
dayofweek = c('day1','day2','day3','day1','day2','day3','day4','day4','day1','day4','day3','day2')
pushupcount = c(100,190,200,220,240,300,210,170,260,150,200,160)
df =  data.frame(id,dayofweek,pushupcount,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Code

```
#arranding data in increasing order of day of week for each id
library('plyr')
df = arrange(df,id,dayofweek)

#adding the new columns
df$cumulativepushups = 0;
df$nextdaypushupcount = 0;

finaldf = NULL;

#the 'cumulativepushups' column is basically a running sum for each id
#the 'nextdaypushupcount' column is number of pushups for that id for the next day
 (NOTE that since on the last day, we do not know how many pushups were done the next day, we consider only till rows n-1)
uniqueid = unique(df$id)
for(i in 1:length(uniqueid))
{
  tempdf = df[which(df$id == uniqueid[i]),]

  for(j in 1:(nrow(tempdf)-1))
  {
    if(j == 1)
    {
      tempdf[j,]$cumulativepushups = tempdf[j,]$pushupcount
    }
    else
    {
      tempdf[j,]$cumulativepushups = tempdf[j-1,]$cumulativepushups + tempdf[j,]$pushupcount
    }

    tempdf[j,]$nextdaypushupcount = tempdf[j+1,]$pushupcount

    finaldf = rbind(finaldf,tempdf[j,])
  }
}
df = finaldf
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `dplyr`.  Order the dataset by "id", "dayofweek" (`arrange(..)`).   Create the "nextdaypushupcount" using `lead` after grouping by "id".  Remove the last
observation for each group (`slice(..)`).  Get the `cumsum` of "pushupcount" to create "cumulativepushups".

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- arrange(df, id, dayofweek)%>%
           group_by(id) %>% 
           mutate(nextdaypushupcount=lead(pushupcount)) %>%
           slice(-n())%>% 
           mutate(cumulativepushups=cumsum(pushupcount))
df1 
 #    id dayofweek pushupcount nextdaypushupcount cumulativepushups
 #1  1      day1           100                240               100
 #2  1      day2           240                200               340
 #3  1      day3           200                170               540
 #4  2      day1           220                190               220
 #5  2      day2           190                300               410
 #6  2      day3           300                150               710
 #7  3      day1           260                160               260
 #8  3      day2           160                200               420
 #9  3      day3           200                210               620
```

#### data

```
id <- c(1,2,3,2,1,2,3,1,3,2,1,3)
dayofweek <- c('day1','day2','day3','day1','day2','day3','day4','day4',
 'day1','day4','day3','day2')
pushupcount <- c(100,190,200,220,240,300,210,170,260,150,200,160)
df <-  data.frame(id,dayofweek,pushupcount,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer and also for the explanation. I still was confused at places, so I was able to understand a few things from the dplyr documentation. I have a couple of questions though. 1.Do we need to do an inner join? Can we just do df1 = arrange(df,id,dayofweek) instead(I get the same o/p) ? 2.Is %>% dplyr syntax? What does it do? Can't google this one because of the characters :)

Comment: @IAMTubby I think you made a good point.  I didn't look the dataset carefully.  Yes, you don't need the inner_join.  You can skip the first step and start from the arrange.  The `%>%` is the chain operator which connects the LHS and RHS.  You can check the documentation  by `?'%>%'`

Comment: I have been able to use the dplyr package effectively and was able to print out all columns using options(dplyr.width = Inf). However, I have one question. Why is it that class(df1) says "grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame". How can I get it to be just a data frame, so I feel more comfortable. (I was able to use this object just like a data frame though, don't see any difference except in the output of class(df1))

Comment: @IAMTubby Just do `df2 <- as.data.frame(df1)`  The `dplyr` adds some class attributes.